# Forum like data structure: NoSQL appropriate?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I'm trying to save data which has a "forum like" structure:

This is the simplified data model:

```
+---------------+
|     Forum     |
|               |
| Name          |
| Category      |
| URL           |
|               |
+---------------+
        |1
        |n
+---------------+
|               |
|     Thread    |
|               |
| ID            |
| Name          |
| Author        |
| Creation Date |
| URL           |
|               |
+---------------+
        |1
        |n
+---------------+
|               |
|      Post     |
|               |
| Creation Date |
| Links         |
| Images        |
|               |
+---------------+
```

I have multiple forums/boards. They can have some threads. A thread can contain n posts (I'm just interested in the links, images and creation date a thread contains for data analysis purposes).

I'm looking for the right technology for saving and reading data in a structure like this.

While I was using SQL databases heavily in the past, I also had some NoSQL projects (primarily document based with MongoDB).
I'm sure MongoDB is excellent for STORING data in such a structure (Forum is a document, while the Threads are subdocuments. Posts are subdocuments in Threads). But what about reading them? I have the following use cases:

- List all posts from a forum with a specific Category
- Find a specific link in a Post in all datasets/documents

Which technology is best for those use cases?

Comment: Reg the second bullet, do you mean links from post, URL from threads and URL from forum? Even though the hierarchy you mentioned as Forum, Thread and Post, I think your use cases access data from Post. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear: I meant Link mentioned in a Post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below my draft solution. I have considered MongoDB for the below design.

**Post Collection:-**

**"image"** should be stored separately in GridFS as MongoDB collection have a maximum size of 16MB. You can store the ObjectId of the image in the Post collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b6f7d78f19ac1e1fcec7b5"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2013-03-16T02:50:27.877Z"),
    "links" : "google.com",
    "image" : ObjectId("5143ddf3bcf1bf4ab37d9c6e"),
    "thread" : [ 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("5143ddf3bcf1bf4ab37d9c6e"),
            "name" : "Sam",
            "author" : "Sam",
            "createdate" : ISODate("2013-03-16T02:50:27.877Z"),
            "url" : "https://www.wikipedia.org/"
        }
    ],
    "forum" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Andy",
            "category" : "technology",
            "url" : "https://www.infoq.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to access the data by category, you can create an index on "forum.category" field.

```
db.post.createIndex( { "forum.category": 1 } )
```

In order to access the data by links, you can create an index on "links" field.

```
db.organizer.createIndex( { "links": 1 } )
```

Please note that the **indexes are not mandatory**. You can access/query the data without index as well. You can create indexes if you need better read performance.

I have seen applications using MongoDB for similar use case as yours. You can go ahead with MongoDB for the above mentioned use cases (or access patterns).